# Don't auto scale zoomable picture box

Tags: c#, visual-studio, zooming, image-scaling

I’m writing in c# with Visual Studio 2013.  I need to have a pixelPictureBox that the user can zoom (1:1 only) and move what parts show.  I also want to make the window it’s in scalable and allow more or less room for the picture.  However, this is causing white space to be added when the 2 shapes don’t match, which is not OK.  I can take care of properly scaling the pixelPictureBox, but I need to stop the automatic scale from happening.  Is there any way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: should have been an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it's actually a problem with the display panel size and the image size.  Before I've zoomed it, the image is bigger than the display area but it still wiggles with a bit of white space when the user drags it one way or the other.

Comment: This question should be closed, but I do not have the privileges to do this.